# React - Fluent UI - How to truncate the text in a card

Tags: reactjs, fluent-ui

I have the example from this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-wood-tscc2h?file=/example.tsx

If the text in the card is too long, the text is clipped. I've been trying to truncate the text so I have some sort of elipses or something similar at the end so the text doesn't look bad but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To truncate the text and show ellipsis (three dots `...`) when the text overflows its container, you can use a combination of CSS styles:

- `white-space: nowrap` to prevent wrapping of the text.
- [`overflowX: hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x) to hide overflowing text for a block-level element's left and right edges.
- [`overflowY: hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y) to hide overflowing text for a block-level element's top and bottom edges.
- `text-overflow: ellipsis` to show an ellipsis when the text overflows its box.

(I tried using [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow), but it kept erroring with: `overflow: string Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)`)

However, for these styles to work, the container needs to have a defined width and not be allowed to grow indefinitely.

Add a new style for the truncating text.

```
truncatedText: {
    whiteSpace: "nowrap",
    overflowX: "hidden",
    overflowY: "hidden",
    textOverflow: "ellipsis",
    maxWidth: "100%"
},
```

Apply the `truncatedText` style to the text you want to truncate; update the `<p>` containing the long text:

```
<p className={`${styles.text} ${styles.truncatedText}`}>
    Donut chocolate bar oat cake. Dragée ...
    // rest of the text
</p>
```

See [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-thunder-gfclv9?file=%2Fexample.tsx)

With these changes, if the text in your card becomes too long for its container, it will be truncated and an ellipsis will be shown.

[image: truncated text]

Note: That will work when the text is expected to fit on one line.

Comment: Isn't it possible to do it to truncate after several lines?

Comment: @user3587624 I actually [just tested multiple lines](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-thunder-gfclv9?file=%2Fexample.tsx), it seems to work (within one paragraph).